# React Native: Opening the IAP billing menu on Android breaks all Animated styles across the app

Tags: react-native

This is perhaps the strangest bug I have ever encountered using React Native, and I'm completely stuck in terms of how to even approach finding a solution.

*Long story short:* Whenever I open the IAP billing menu on Android, all Animated styles across the entire app stop working until I close the menu.

[This is what the view looks like before trying to make an IAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXy4s.jpg).
Correct.
[This is what the view looks like when trying to make an IAP
on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4mA7.png). Incorrect.

[Screen recording.](https://i.imgur.com/6RyPO1J.mp4)

It seems as if most, if not all Animated math function (interpolate, multiply, etc.) styles through-out the app stop working as you open up the IAP menu. As you can see in the images above, [the pagination arrow on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3TLi.png) gets flipped the wrong way because the style transformation depending both Animated.interpolate and Animated.multiply stops working. All other visual bugs happen for the same reasons.

Has anyone encountered anything like this, or have suggestions where I should start looking for the root of the problem?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's all because of `useNativeDriver: true`. You're killing me Android, why are you so hard to make a good user experience on.

**Edit:** I managed to create what looks to be an invisible workaround.

I created a global state that toggles `useNativeDriver` for animations that were affected by the bug. I keep my purchase request in a saga, and turn the state off just before the purchase is called for, then immediately back on when it finishes.